# What is the meaning of the verb 围？Its subject and object?

Tags: verbs, terminology

四合院，是中国华北地区民居中的一种组合建筑形式。所谓四合，“四”指东、西、南、北四面，“合” 就是四面房屋围在一起，中间形成一个方形的院子。

Hi all. I found this in the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 14. What is the meaning of the verb 围？What are its subject and object in this sentence?

提前感谢。

Answer (score 2):

围 means to surround.

护城河围着城堡
The moat surrounds the castle.

四面房屋围在一起
The buildings from all four sides surround together.

So the subject is the 四面房屋(buildings from all four sides) and the verb is 围

For the object, I think there is not any, or it is the middle space which is implied.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I think it needs an edit about the double term "subject".

Comment: @SEnergeiakos ah sorry, the second should be the object. Edited

Comment: @SEnergeiakos Also I'm not sure if the verb surround is intransitive or transitive, so maybe there is a better verb for it in English?

Answer (score 2):

围: surround; gather around

The subject is 四面房屋 (buildings from four sides)

**围在一起** here means "**wall up**; **gather together**"

中间形成一个方形的院子 - and form a square shape courtyard

we don't need an object for the verb **gather together**

BTW, 四合院 literally means 'Four (sides/ buildings) formed courtyard'